# Conditionals for an index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an index.html.erb view, which iterates the following:

```
<% @user_contents.each do |user_content| %>

<% end %>
```

My problem is that I need to render a form when the file is empty, for that content.

I've already set the @content this way:

```
def set_content
   @content = Content.find(params[:content_id])
end
```

That works fine, but I've been trying some conditionals like this:

```
<% if user_content.content.id == @content %>
  <% if user_content.file.blank? %>
   *Here I want to render my partial*
  <% else %>
   *Here I want to render a card*
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But this doesn't work. I'll really appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Describe please *But this doesn't work..* . What is not working?

Comment: tryr `if user_content.content.id == @content.id` or `if user_content.content == @content`

Answer (score 0):

avoid nested conditions, you can do it like this

```
<% if user_content.content.id.eql?(params[:id]) && user_content.file.present? %>
   *Here i want to render a card*
<% else %>
   *Here i want to render my partial*
<% end %>
```